# C#.NET Equiv for Python's urllib2.Request()

Tags: c#, python, .net, http

I need to know two things, first thing is, what exactly does the urllib2.Request() from python do? I found it in some python sample code, and I am trying to translate it to C#, my second question is, is there a C# equiv?

Comment: Have you tried [looking at the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html)? Even if someone tells you the basics of what it does, you're _still_ going to need the docs to get the specifics if you want to port it to a different library (and language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it does, it essentially initializes an instance of the urllib2 class, which I know how to emulate with WebClient in C#.NET, thank you for your responses though.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Roman's answer the python function performs an HTTP request.

If you are working with .NET 4 or greater you should consider using HttpClient() which supports Async calling and pretty complete formatting (Json,XML) should you need it.

Details at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

I also agree with Roman that RestSharp is definitely worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

That function performs an HTTP request and returns response headers.

As of C#/.NET, start looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Also look for open-source, such as http://restsharp.org/